# wp_list_pages, hide parent with no ancestor and show children to chosen post

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am trying to create a menu using wp_list_pages and I want the end result to look like this:

```
parent ( no ancestor ) <-- This one should be hidden
  - Children "Some Title"( clicked )
    - Children1 to "Some Title"
    - Children2 to "Some Title"

  - Children "Some other title" ( When clicking on this, children to "Somte Title" will hide and children to "Some other title" show )
```

I am using the following code, and I cant figure out how to modify it to give me the result I want.

```
<?php
//if the post has a parent
if($post->post_parent){
    //collect ancestor pages
    $relations = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);

    //get child pages
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $post->ID AND post_type='page'" );
    if ($result){
        foreach($result as $pageID){
            array_push($relations, $pageID->ID);
        }
    }

    //add current post to pages
    array_push($relations, $post->ID);
    //get comma delimited list of children and parents and self
    $relations_string = implode(",",$relations);

    //use include to list only the collected pages.
    $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&include=".$relations_string); 
}else{
    // display only main level and children

    $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID);
}

if ($sidelinks) { ?>
    <?php echo the_title(); ?>
    <ul>
        <?php //links in <li> tags
        echo $sidelinks;
        ?>

    </ul>
<?php } ?>
```

The example above gives me a layout looking like this and it shows the parent with no ancestor and not the sibling to the clicked Children:

```
parent ( no ancestor )
  - Children "Some Title"( clicked )
    - Children1 to "Some Title"
    - Children2 to "Some Title"
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exclude_tree` and `depth` parameters of wp_list_pages()

See the Wordpress Codex for more info: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for answering. I'am not sure how this is supposed to work? If I want to hide the main parent that has no ancestors using exclude_tree, wouldent that would remove all children attached to it? Then it would come up blank. Can you perhaps make a small example that maps to my code above?

Comment: I think if you just want to show the children, and not the parent, you will do like `wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&child_of=".$post->ID);` So, in this case don't use the `depth` parameter and the result should return all children of the parent. Hope that helps. Also, keep in mind you have a conditional statement, so if `$sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&include=".$relations_string);` doesn't result in true, you get `$sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID);` by your code.

Comment: $sidelinks = wp_list_pages("title_li=&echo=0&depth=1&child_of=".$post->ID); seems to work except that the siblings to the choosen post doesnt show. Siblings should show, but not the children to the siblings. Only the children to the selected post shall be visible.